# How do I resolve BeanCreationException due to the 'entityManagerFactory' etc...?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

So I"m dealing with the infamous `BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'`. I've tried everything I came across on here and on Google, but still I"m unable to get my Spring app to run. Here's the message I get:

```java
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[2m2020-03-02 22:35:33.897[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m16908[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.mapping.SingleTableSubclass cannot be cast to org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.volapp.VolappApplication.main(VolappApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.mapping.SingleTableSubclass cannot be cast to org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder.bind(PropertyBinder.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder.makePropertyValueAndBind(PropertyBinder.java:205) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:2282) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:975) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:802) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:254) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:230) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:273) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1202) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1233) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378) ~[spring-orm-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

I'd appreciate any help getting this resolved.

Comment: Post your hibernate entities those are causing issue.

Comment: Maybe you are using @Id in any subclass. Remove id from Subclass.